# Example of unique factorization failure in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given $\zeta_{23} = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{23}}$, the extension $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ is not a unique factorization domain according to many sources.

Because I don't know how to work with these things (e.g., in Sage, attempting to factor in this ring creates an infinite loop), I am interested in an example of an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ that factors into multiple distinct products of irreducibles. If possible, we would like to use a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ that is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ for the example, and document your procedure for producing the example such that an outsider can follow.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183760/mathbbz-omega-is-not-a-ufd), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551299/unique-factorization-fails-in-cyclotomic-integers-for-p-23), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873941/finding-ideal-representatives-in-the-class-group-of-mathbbq-zeta-23), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496320/when-is-bbbz-zeta-n-a-pid)

Comment: Thank you for those related questions. I came across them while attempting to produce an example and they brought me no closer to a method.